# How to make Snooker holes with boolean?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to create a Snooker table for a Snooker PC game. I use Boolean to make the Snooker holes once, but then I had to make it all again in another project. I created a new project to do that but now the modifier is not working. When I use difference boolean it cuts the pool table and stays just with the cylinder, have no idea why it isn't working. I already saw some threads talking about normals and remove doubles but it is still not working. I put the blender file here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Tables Z scale is negative, so change it from -0.192 to 0.192 and then rotate Y 180 degrees. Also cylinder scales are all negatives (X, Y and Z are all -0.304) change them all to 0.304. After you get rid of those negative scales try again if it works now as it should.

Comment: sorry for my newbie question but my scale is 1 1 1, what you mean with z scale is negative and how can i change it?

Comment: Added image. This is what i see when i open provided blend file.

Comment: you are my hero thanks dude, something changed in my actual file i opened the untitled again and you where right perfect :D

Comment: I guess you applied scale accidentally :P That changes values to 1